# How to preserve the volume of a dynamic signal that varies in pitch?

Tags: audio, volume, pitch

I'm creating some audio dynamically (with WebAudio), by starting with basic oscillators (sine/square/etc) and applying various modulations. Naturally, as I change the pitch of the signals the apparent volume changes, with higher pitches sounding louder and lower pitches quieter.

My question is, is there some standard way of processing the signal to keep a (vaguely) constant volume as its pitch changes? Of course I could just add a gain node and twiddle it up and down in some ad-hoc way, but I'm guessing there's a standard thing to do here (which I've looked for but can't find).

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the [Fletcher-Munson curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%E2%80%93Munson_curves) and other similar results. You can try to approximate what you think the dB SPL output of the speakers are an adjust your tone volumes from there. Otherwise, if you don't feel the need to be so scientific, you can just apply  something resembling the Fletcher-Munson curve to get a good enough volume adjustment for typical listening volumes.

Comment: @Linuxios Thanks, yeah - when there were no responses I wound up finding those curves, fitting a line to one, and adjusting based on the result. I'll post the formula I came up with as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's apparently no standard approach to this, here's the "solution" I hacked out:

```
function getVolumeAdjustment(freq) {
    var x = Math.log(freq)
    var db = 3.4 * x * x - 49.3 * x + 217
    return db - 45
}
```

`db` vaguely approximates the 40-phon [Equal Loudness contour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal-loudness_contour), at least as I eyeballed it from the picture on wikipedia. I then subtract 45 so that I have a volume adjustment (ranging from -6 to 15 or so) to be applied to each given tone based on its frequency.

It seems to basically work - still happy to hear any better answers though.

Comment: Important note: the equal-loudness contour indicates relative volumes in dB SPL (sound pressure level), which is a real world volume. Obviously, there's no guaranteed way to convert dBFS (digital dB) to real world dB SPL or vise versa, but it's worth remembering that they *are* different units that aren't being converted here.